# I get this error when i compile my code: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'lower'

Tags: python

This is my code:

```
def add_list(list):
  sum = 0
  for item in list:
    sum += list[item - 1]

  return sum

def summarize(list):
  print("The sum of " + str(list) + " is " + str(add_list(list)) + ".")


summarize([int(1),int(2),int(3)])
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It works for me with using the provided input.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have `summarize` return a value:

```
def summarize(list):
    return "The sum of " + str(list) + " is " + str(add_list(list)) + "."
```

Otherwise, `None` will be returned by default.  This means that when you do something like:

```
var = summarize([int(1),int(2),int(3)])
```

`var` will be assigned to `None` and calling `.lower()` on it will raise an `AttributeError`.